# How to get parent object of fields in a report using Apex

Tags: apex

I've been using apex to gather all the info I can from a report. This includes report name, type, filters, fields, date created etc. I also want to see what object its fields belong to.

[image]

Take a look at these fields for this report. I know I can manually look up the field name in object manager and find its parent object, but I want to automate that using apex. Any help is appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It can be done with a callout to [Reports REST API Description](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_analytics.meta/api_analytics/sforce_analytics_rest_api_getbasic_reportmetadata.htm):

```
String reportId = '00O8W0000036obT';

Http http = new Http();
HttpRequest req = new HttpRequest();
req.setEndpoint(URL.getSalesforceBaseUrl().toExternalForm() + '/services/data/v51.0/analytics/reports/' + reportId + '/describe');
req.setHeader('Authorization', 'Bearer ' + UserInfo.getSessionId());
req.setMethod('GET');

HttpResponse res = http.send(req);
Map<String, Object> resBody = (Map<String, Object>) JSON.deserializeUntyped(res.getBody());
Map<String, Object> reportExtendedMetadata = (Map<String, Object>) resBody.get('reportExtendedMetadata');
Map<String, Object> detailColumnInfo = (Map<String, Object>) reportExtendedMetadata.get('detailColumnInfo');
for (String key : detailColumnInfo.keySet()) {
    Map<String, Object> tmp = (Map<String, Object>) detailColumnInfo.get(key);
    System.debug((String) tmp.get('label') + ' -> ' + (String) tmp.get('entityColumnName') + ' -> ' + ((String) tmp.get('entityColumnName'))?.substringBefore('.')); 
// Company / Account -> Lead.Company -> Lead
}
```

Comment: Wow, that really solved my entire problem. I had been trying to figure this one for days but couldn't get it to work. Thank you so much for your help and quick response.

Comment: Not at all) If this answer is helpful, please, accept it. @apexdev